# why compiling of bootloader is mentioning error TIMES value -9 is negative?

Tags: assembly, nasm, dos, x86-16, bootloader

thanks patch i got a bootloader code from another account of github proveded by you. thanks patch you guide me for msdos bootloader code
but when i compile this bootloader code then it shows below given error, how can i adjust my code, why this error is appearing:

```
TIMES value -9 is negative
```

the complete bootloader code is as given below:

```
%include "bios/config.asm"

org 0x7c00
base:
jmp start
nop

db  "PETYADOS"  ; OEM
dw  0x0200      ; bytes per sector
clstsz: db  0x01        ; sectors per cluster
rsvds:  dw  0x01        ; reserved sectors
nfats:  db  0x02        ; number of FATs
ndire:  dw  0x00e0      ; number of dir entries
dw  0x0b40      ; number of sectors
db  0xf0        ; media descriptor
fatsz:  dw  0x0009      ; sectors per FAT
nsect:  dw  0x0012      ; sectors per head
nhead:  dw  0x0002      ; heads per cylinder
dd  0x000000000 ; hidden sectors
dd  0x000000000 ; large total logical sectors
db  0x00        ; physical drive number
db  0x00        ; flags
db  0x00        ; extended boot signature
dd  0x12345678  ; volume serial number
db  "DOS        "   ; volume label
times   8 db 0      ; filesystem type

start:  mov bx, [si + 8]
cli ; Don't rely on the interrupt shadow (some CPUs are buggy)
xor ax, ax
mov ss, ax
mov sp, STKTOP
xor ax, ax
mov ds, ax
mov es, ax
cld
sti

mov [drive], dl
test    dl, 0x80
jz  .floppy
mov [poff], bx
.floppy:

; load IO.SYS and MSDOS.SYS

mov word [cseg], 0x70
mov word [cname], ionam
call    loadfile

mov word [cseg], 0x280
mov word [cname], dosnam
call    loadfile

; transfer control to IO.SYS

mov dl, [drive]
mov ax, 0x70
mov ds, ax
mov es, ax
jmp 0x70:0

loadfile:
mov ax, [fatsz]
mov bl, [nfats]
xor bh, bh
mul bx
add ax, [rsvds]
mov bx, [ndire]
add bx, 15
mov cl, 4
shr bx, cl
mov [resid], bx
push    ax
call    seek
.nextdt:push    word [cseg] ; XXX
mov word [cseg], DIRBUF >> 4
call    read
pop word [cseg] ; XXX

; find the directory entry

mov di, DIRBUF
.next:  mov si, [cname]
mov cx, 11
rep cmpsb
je  .found
and di, 0xffe0
add di, 32
cmp di, DIRBUF + 512
jne .next
dec word [resid]
cmp word [resid], 0
jne .nextdt
jmp fail

; calculate the first sector CHS address of the file

.found: mov ax, [di + 0x1a - 11] ; first cluster
sub ax, 2
mov bl, [clstsz]
xor bh, bh
mul bx
pop bx
add ax, bx
mov bx, [ndire]
add bx, 15
mov cl, 4
shr bx, cl
add ax, bx
call    seek

; calculate the number of sectors to load

mov cx, [di + 0x1c - 11] ; file size
add cx, 511
mov cl, ch
shr cl, 1
xor ch, ch
mov word [resid], cx

; load the file

.load:  call    read
add word [cseg], 0x20
dec word [resid]
cmp word [resid], 0
jne .load

seek:   add ax, [poff]
xor dx, dx
mov bx, word [nsect]
div bx
inc dx
mov byte [csect], dl
xor dx, dx
mov bx, word [nhead]
div bx
mov byte [chead], dl
mov [ccyl], ax
ret

read:   push    es
mov ax, word [cseg]
mov es, ax
mov ax, 0x0201
mov ch, byte [ccyl]
mov cl, byte [ccyl + 1]
ror cl, 1
ror cl, 1
or  cl, byte [csect]
mov dh, byte [chead]
mov dl, byte [drive]
xor bx, bx
int 0x13
jc  fail
pop es
inc byte [csect]
mov cl, [nsect]
cmp [csect], cl
jbe .fini
mov byte [csect], 1
inc byte [chead]
mov cl, [nhead]
cmp [chead], cl
jb  .fini
mov byte [chead], 0
inc byte [ccyl]
.fini:  ret

fail:   mov bx, 0x0007
mov ah, 0x0e
mov si, .msg
.loop:  lodsb
test    al, al
jz  .halt
int 0x10
jmp .loop
.halt:  xor ah, ah
int 0x16
int 0x19
.msg    db  13, 10, "Not a system disk or d", 13, 10, 0

dosnam  db  "MSDOS   SYS"
ionam   db  "IO      SYS"

ccyl    dw  0
chead   db  0
csect   db  0
cseg    dw  0xb800
cname   dw  0
drive   db  0
resid   dw  0
poff    dw  0

times   0x01fe - ($ - $$) db 0
dw  0xaa55
```

again i mentioning the error:

```
TIMES value -9 is negative
```

Comment: You can pass the `-Ox` or `-O2` switch to NASM. Recent versions of NASM default to enable that (can be overridden with `-O0`). With optimisations enabled the file assembles fine.

Comment: For reference here is the prior question: [Where can I find a good MS-DOS bootloader code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64682943/where-can-i-find-a-good-ms-dos-bootloader-code) and here is [the boot.asm at the revision](https://github.com/p-durlej/dosbios/blob/9722a72b21fde6a9bd986c0c9bd4fdfa8b414a81/boot/boot.asm) which I assembled. Using NASM 2.15 without any switches (same as `-Ox`) it assembles, passing `-O0` makes it return the error message you indicated.

Comment: What version of NASM are you using? What is the output of `nasm -v`

Answer (score 1):

You're nine bytes too large to fit in the boot sector.

Need to squeeze nine bytes out of that asm file.

Here's a start:

```
start:  mov bx, [si + 8]
cli ; Don't rely on the interrupt shadow (some CPUs are buggy)
xor ax, ax
mov ss, ax
mov sp, STKTOP
xor ax, ax
mov ds, ax
mov es, ax
cld
sti
```

can be optimized by two bytes (patch went wrong?)

```
start:
cli ; Don't rely on the interrupt shadow (some CPUs are buggy)
mov bx, [si + 8] ;Save before clobbering segs
xor ax, ax
mov ss, ax
mov ds, ax
mov es, ax
mov sp, STKTOP
cld
sti
```

Actually we can do one better yet. There's a free byte at the very start occupied by that nop. Let's help ourselves.

```
base:
cli
jmp short start
```

Now we don't need the `cli` after start.

```
start:
mov bx, [si + 8] ;Save before clobbering segs
```

`drive`, `poff` `cseg`, `cname` are all written to before they're read so they can just be moved to safe , such as the first 8 bytes past `start`. There's 8 bytes. it all fits.

One last thing: `jmp start` make very sure this is a short jump (two bytes long) or the whole thing won't work.

Comment: The original code was written with an 8086 in mind. This bootloader is part of an MS-DOS 1.25 and MS-DOS 2.00 restoration project so they specifically made 8086 the lowest common denominator. https://github.com/p-durlej/dosbios

Comment: @MichaelPetch: In which case why doesn't it do what DOS originally did and have a plain old different boot sector for FD than for HD?

Comment: Because they are trying to be smarter than the original developers. What is well established over the past 35+ years is that it is possible to write a boot sector that covers a wider range of devices with the same boot sector and read the actual files from the FAT file system without them being in a fixed location.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: Check it out. I made it all fit.

Comment: How would an assembler waste bytes on `sub ax, 2`?  It's either opcode + imm16 or opcode + modrm + imm8.  An assembler would have to be total garbage to use the `add r/m16, imm16` opcode for that; that seems implausible.  If you want to save a byte there, you have to use `dec ax` / `dec ax` (2 bytes total), an optimization assemblers can't do because it has a different architectural effect (doesn't modify CF, and is 2 insns so TF would raise 2 debug interrupts.)  [Tips for golfing in x86/x64 machine code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/132981)

Comment: Oh I upvoted your answer and saw your last edit to get this down by 9 bytes. Some of the routines aren't as efficient as they can be as well and can be rewritten especially the code that does the LBA to CHS conversion.

Comment: @PeterCordes: oops. I think I dropped a 32 bit specific one in there. :(

Comment: Just a side note. The OP mentioning "Patch" in the question was a misspelling of my name since I provided a link to this restoration project as a comment to a question of theirs that was closed earlier today.

Comment: thanks josua, there is problem, when i modify my code as mentioned by you, i shifted drive, poff, cseg, cname to the upper part of the code past start. but i have still the same problem of "TIMES value -9 is negative". could you please post the whole bootloader code in the way mentioned by you, i am unable to understand the modifications mentioned by you, so please give me the whole bootloader code. i am grateful to you.

Comment: This looks like NASM syntax, based on the use of `times`, and `word []` instead of `word ptr []`.  NASM is not total garbage, so will reliably pick `sub eax, sign_extended_imm8` when the value is an assemble-time constant `2`.  But like I said, `dec` / `dec` would be smaller, still worth mentioning.  Anyway, there are huge amounts of missed optimizations, like `test dl, 0x80` / `jnz` instead of `test dl,dl` / `js`.  And using CL/CX instead of AL/AX, missing out on special case AX encodings.  And general wasted instructions like `cmp word [resid], 0` / `jne` right after a `dec`

Comment: @javtiwari: The labels need to overlap the instructions. No dw 0 for them.

Comment: @PeterCordes: I've got a nasm binary lying around that's a lot dumber. It literally did not know to generate sub eax, sign_extended_imm8 unless you told it to. It didn't generate short jumps either unless told to do so.

Comment: thanks, Jashua, i am a beginner in boot code programming, so would you help by posting the whole code, please.

Comment: Perhaps in old versions, `-Ox` (multi-pass optimization) wasn't the default like it has been for years?  There is a `-O0` option which makes modern NASM that dumb (`sub eax, imm32`) unless you use `sub eax, byte 2`.

Comment: @javtiwari: If I was going to do that I'd make a PR onto that project myself.

Comment: @Peter Cordes: Indeed using `-O0` with a recent version of NASM and the original source (referenced in my comment; I think OP didn't properly copy it) allows me to reproduce the error.

Comment: @ecm: Oh weird, was NASM braindead by default until recently, or is the OP using a *very* old verison?  NASM has optimized branch displacements and immediate sizes by default since at *least* 2015, probably years earlier; it would be really weird not to do so.  IDK why anyone would be using a NASM version more than 5 years old in 2020, but I guess that explains it.